# How to mark a property as Sensitive in an SSIS Custom Connection Manager so you can use Sensitive Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have an existing Custom Data Connector for SSIS, and I want to use Sensitive Parameters with it, specifically for the 'Password' property.

When I attempt to 'Parameterize' the connection, it tells me I can't use a Sensitive Parameter as the Property isn't marked as Sensitive.

In terms of reading/writing the configuration XML, the property *is* output encrypted, but I want to use Parameters.

I have tried adding the `SensitiveStringAttribute` to the `Password` Property:

```cs
[SensitiveString(true)] public string Password { get; set; } = "";
```

But this is not recognised as a sensitive property.

I can't find another `Sensitive*` attribute in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTS.Runtime` library - but I assume there is one - as parameters don't have to be strings.

**What do I need to do to mark a Property in my C# code as Sensitive so that SSIS can use Sensitive Parameters to set it?**

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal example of your code?

Comment: Not easily - the best example would be to take something like https://github.com/kzhen/SSISRabbitMQ (in particular https://github.com/kzhen/SSISRabbitMQ/blob/master/SSISRabbitMQ.RabbitMQConnectionManager/RabbitMQConnectionManager.cs) and you can see there is a property there for Password. If you use that connection manager - you can't set that property to being a Sensitive Parameter.

Comment: Interesting. Okay... a couple of things. 1) Can you point to the documentation of the SensitiveString decorator? Maybe my search-fu is weak today but I'm not finding it. 2) Let's say that we somehow get a sensitive string. At some point, you need to marshal it into a form that whatever you're trying to connect to is expecting. Which, unless I'm totally off base, is just a bog standard string. So it would be unprotected by whatever mechanism SensitiveString provides. All of which is to say - what are you trying to protect against?

Comment: Sure: 1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.sensitivestringattribute?view=sqlserver-2019 - but I think this is not the right attribute - as many properties can be Sensitive - I suspect more `DTSProperty`. As to 2) - SSIS allows you to store things like passwords, or any other field as a sensitive parameter. If someone does that - to assign it to a property on a custom component, that property needs to be 'sensitive'. Generally it's used to prevent everyone working on a package knowing the passwords etc